# TestCocoon code coverage with shared library?

Tags: c++, linux, testing, code-coverage, testcocoon

I'm using testcocoon to instrument a library I'm working on. The problem is once I build the library with testcocoon, generating csmes files(which is the way it should be), I cannot get the coverage results in the final executable.

The library is built as a dynamic library (*.so file) and the executable is also built with testcocoon. The coverage results show only the source files of the executables, nothing about the library is present in the result.

Has anyone have similar experiences with testcocoon?